# Is there an equivalent for In-App Review for Huawei services

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services

I just implemented the In - App Review SDK for my application. But this will work on devices that have Google services as I understand it.

Is there an equivalent to In - App review for Huawei devices without Google services or in this case should I invite the user to rate the app through a link to the App Gallery?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Huawei has their own solution for in-app reviews targeting the huawei app gallery, which can be triggered for released apps this way:

```
val intent = Intent("com.huawei.appmarket.intent.action.guidecomment")
intent.setPackage("com.huawei.appmarket")
activityContext.startActivityForResult(intent, inAppReviewResultCode)
```

You find the official documentation [here](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-comments-develop-0000001062858332).

Answer (score 1):

There is no useful `SDK` yet.

If you have no Google services like on the Huawei P40, I suggest to use the App Gallery.
Why?:

> Because the next popular rate widget is in App Gallery.
> People don't
> like change, so they will maximum use the next big thing.

[Here](https://www.androidauthority.com/huawei-app-gallery-review-1101306/) is a good article for decision making.